# ng-model no longer updates after typing into text input

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ngmodel

I am new to AngularJS and I am having a problem that I am having trouble solving, there was a similar question on stackoverflow but it didn't seem to help me out. I basically have a form that gets updated by ng-click, but once once I enter text into any of the text boxes, those text boxes no longer update.

This is my HTML

```
Edit Course:
<li ng-repeat="course in courses">
  <p>
    <a ng-click="Edit_Course(course.id)">{{course.course_name}}</a>
  </p>
</li>
<div ng-show="showedit == 1">
  <form novalidate ng-submit="edit_course()" class="simple-form">
    <label for="form_course_name">Course</label>
      <input type="text" id="form_course_name" ng-model="edit_course_name">
    <label for="form_par">Par</label>
      <input type="text" id="form_par" ng-model="edit_course_par">
    <label for="form_course_location">Course Location</label>
      <input type="text" id="form_course_location" ng-model="edit_course_location">
     <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Edit Course" />
   </form>
</div>
```

This is my function that is called when someone clicks on a link

```
$scope.Edit_Course = function (id) {
    var course = {
        'course_id' : id
    };

    $http({method: "POST", url: "http://www.dgcharts.com/editcourse", data: course})
    .success(function(data, status, headers, config){

      thecourse = data["course"];
      $scope.edit_course_name = thecourse.course_name;
      $scope.edit_course_par = thecourse.par;
      $scope.edit_course_location = thecourse.course_location;
      $scope.edit_course_id = thecourse.id;
      $scope.showedit = 1;
  })
}
```

Answer (score 116, accepted):

your link requires a login.

if i have to guess about your problem, it may be related to angular scoping issue.  try changing your ng-model binding to an object property instead.  so in your html, instead of:

```
<input type="text" id="form_course_name" ng-model="edit_course_name">
```

do this

```
<input type="text" id="form_course_name" ng-model="course.edit_course_name">
```

and in your javascript, on the ajax callback, change it to:

```
$scope.course = {};  //only do this if $scope.course has not already been declared
$scope.course.edit_course_name = thecourse.course_name;
```

for more info on this issue, see: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes

Comment: thank you very much, that fixed it in about 60 seconds. I'll definitely read up on scopes before I continue with this project, because I clearly don't understand them fully.

Comment: @EvWill nice explanation why it does not work with primitive here https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes

Comment: I was using it wrong way for more than one month, thank you so much. If this is not the correct way, then Angular should not allow devs to write the code that way. This problem horrified me for complete two nights. :D

Comment: had the same problem in scope but related to ng-include. Very helpful link

Comment: That link was a life-saver, it made all the difference to my understanding of Angular scopes and finally documents how transclusions and scope binding work! I'd been trying to figure those out for months and this one article put it all together for me in clear, simple terms.

Comment: Tnx very much! for some reason after a year ng-model stopped to work just like that. After wrapping it into {} object it miraculously started to work again.