# Issues with ngModel Binding

Tags: angularjs

I am facing issues with binding in Angular.

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <li> Discount
      <input ng-change="update_amount()" type="number" ng-model="discount" />
    </li>
     <li> Other Charges
      <input ng-change="update_amount()" type="number" ng-model="others" />
     </li>
</div>
```

JS:

```
ng.module('app').controller('myCtrl', [
  '$scope',
  function ($scope) {
    $scope.removeRestaurantFromActiveCall = function () {
      $scope.updateActiveCall(function (call) {
        call.restaurant = null;
      });
    };

    $scope.showModal = false ;
    $scope.others = 0 ;
    $scope.discount = 0 ;


    $scope.update_amount = function () {
      console.log('Change called') ;


      console.log($scope.others) ;    // Always zero
      console.log($scope.discount) ;  // Always zero

      console.log($scope) ;  // Does not have the current value for my fields
      console.log(this) ; // Has current values for my field

      console.log($scope === this) ; // False
      console.log($scope == this) ;  // False

    }  ; }) ;
```

I get the values for my field in `this` but not in `scope`. Not even sure about what the `this` is referring to here.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Are you sure above snippet is working ? Your controller declaration is not matching with the Markup.

Comment: <div ng-controller="myCtrl"> here your controller name is `myCtrl` and you are trying to access the properties on another controller `app.leftPane.restaurant`

Comment: My bad. The controller name is fine in the actual code. Was just trying to shorten it here. Forgot to make the changes in both the places

Comment: This is just part of the code for brevity. Actual code does not have the syntax error.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ng-model no longer updates after typing into text input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19310129/ng-model-no-longer-updates-after-typing-into-text-input)

Comment: Duplicate confirmed. The answer fixed my issue. Thanks!

Comment: You can remember this rule of thumb mentionned in the [Angular Documentation](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes): you should have a dot in your ng-model.

Answer (score 0):

Check it out here is working fine :--

```js
 function MyController($scope) {

   $scope.removeRestaurantFromActiveCall = function() {
     $scope.updateActiveCall(function(call) {
       call.restaurant = null;
     });
   };

   $scope.showModal = false;
   $scope.others = 0;
   $scope.discount = 0;


   $scope.update_amount = function() {
     console.log('Change called');


     console.log($scope.others); // Always zero
     console.log($scope.discount); // Always zero

     console.log($scope); // Does not have the current value for my fields
     console.log(this); // Has current values for my field

     console.log($scope === this); // False
     console.log($scope == this); // False



   };
 };
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app ng-controller="MyController">
  <li>Discount
    <input ng-change="update_amount()" type="number" ng-model="discount" />
  </li>
  <li>Other Charges
    <input ng-change="update_amount()" type="number" ng-model="others" />
  </li>

  <p>{{"discount =" + discount}}</p>
  <p>{{"others =" + others}}</p>
</div>
```