# AngularJS not sending scope data to php

Tags: ajax, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a problem sending the data of a simple textfield (currentlinkedin) to a php file with angularjs. In the template I have the code

```
<div id="linkedin" ng-show="showLinkedIn" class="cssSlideUp">
<br/>Link to your linkedin profile: <br/>
<input type="txt" ng-model="currentlinkedin"/><br/><br/>
<input type="submit" ng-click="saveLinkedin()" value="Opslagen"/>
</div>
```

In controllerjs I have following code

```
$scope.saveLinkedin=function(){

$http({
    method  : 'POST',
    url     : '/cvmentorgit/savelinkedin.php',
    data    : { linkedin : $scope.currentlinkedin},
    headers : { 'Content-Type': 'undefined' }
 })
  .success(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    $scope.savelinkedinfeedback="Linkedin-profiel opgeslagen";
  });
}
```

In savelinkedin.php php code: $linkedin = addslashes($_POST["linkedin"]);       gives the error "Notice undefined index linkedin" and nothing is saved. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your php you can take postData with `file_get_contents("php://input")` ;

```
$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
$formData = json_decode($postdata);
echo $formData->linkedin;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this an angular scope issue similar to the this [thread.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19310129/ng-model-no-longer-updates-after-typing-into-text-input)

Have **currentlinked to be a property of an object** as follows:

In your **controller**:

```
$scope.obj = {};
$scope.obj.currentlinkedin = ''; //initialise it
```

In your **HTML**:

```
<input type="txt" ng-model="obj.currentlinkedin"/><br/><br/>
```