# Nested object inside scope object in custom directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Why can't I have a binding in a nested object in my scope object like this:

```
app.directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
        scope: {
            dropdown: {
                option: '=selectedOption' //not working
            } 
        }
    }
})
```

I am getting an error:

> a.match is not a function

Here's a [working plunker.](https://plnkr.co/edit/5xPn5dOX9G2Z1EBZIe9q?p=preview)

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I want a variable in my directive which is a property of an object and is binded to a variable in the controller.

Comment: So have you tried like this: `scope: { "dropdown.option": "=selectedOption" }`?

Comment: No, that looks weird, but let me try.

Comment: No, its not working.

Comment: can you just fiddle it out.

Comment: Sure, just give me a moment.

Comment: Added the plunker in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to "why" is "because that isn't how it works".

The AngularJS source code that parses the scope for a directive is here: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/compile.js#L829

```
  function parseIsolateBindings(scope, directiveName, isController) {
    var LOCAL_REGEXP = /^\s*([@&]|=(\*?))(\??)\s*(\w*)\s*$/;

    var bindings = {};

    forEach(scope, function(definition, scopeName) {
      var match = definition.match(LOCAL_REGEXP);

      if (!match) {
        throw $compileMinErr('iscp',
            "Invalid {3} for directive '{0}'." +
            " Definition: {... {1}: '{2}' ...}",
            directiveName, scopeName, definition,
            (isController ? "controller bindings definition" :
            "isolate scope definition"));
      }

      bindings[scopeName] = {
        mode: match[1][0],
        collection: match[2] === '*',
        optional: match[3] === '?',
        attrName: match[4] || scopeName
      };
    });

    return bindings;
  }
```

As you can see, it does a single pass through the `scope` object properties and does not recursively descend into object properties.

Comment: Got it, so it isn't possible. Can this be called as a bug? Because it is an accepted good practice to not have direct bindings to scope and this limits us to having direct bindings to scope in directives?

Comment: @TarunDugar Seems like a reasonable request to me. You can submit issues on GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will work or not:

```
scope: {
    "dropdown.option": "=selectedOption"
}
```

But, as a workaround, you can write like this:

```
app.directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
        scope: {
            dropdownOption: "=selectedOption"
        },
        controller: ["$scope", function($scope) {
            $scope.dropdown = $scope.dropdown || {};

            $scope.$watch('dropdownOption', function(newValue) {
                $scope.dropdown.option = newValue;
            });


            $scope.$watch('dropdown.option', function(newValue) {
                $scope.dropdownOption = newValue;
            });
        }]
    }
})
```

Comment: First one does not work. Second one is a workaround agreed but the question is why cant we have nested objects as mentioned.

Comment: Oh! right Tarun. Not sure about the reason but probably, Angular itself doesn't supports it. Have you seen such an example out there?

Comment: No, I haven't but its a well known good practice of avoiding direct bindings with scope properties. Otherwise I can have issues like these: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19310129/ng-model-no-longer-updates-after-typing-into-text-input. And I am also just plain curious as to why this isn't support(if it isn't). :)

Comment: Yeah, that's true. I'll delete my answer then.